# Java SimpleDateFormat , How to get the pattern used?

Tags: java, date-format

I have SimpleDateFormat object like this,

`SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("'INCDR'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_ss_SSS'*.csv'");`

Here the format `"'INCDR'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_ss_SSS'*.csv'"` is configurable.

I want to extract only this `yyyy,MM,dd,HH,ss & SSS` part from it. How can I do that?

Please note that pattern is configurable with valid java date format symbols.

eg: Another pattern `"HH_ss_SSS_'INCDR'_yyyy_MM_dd'*.csv'"`

Comment: How about using regex to cut regular expressions out? or even rawFormat.replace('firstConstant',"").replace('secondConstant',"")?

Comment: @Antoniossss, these aren't constants. As per the OP, `'INCR'` and the suffix are all part of one configurable string.

Comment: @Isaac you are right, I did not get it that those are configurables

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract just a part of the pattern. The closest you can get is the `.toPattern()` method on `SimpleDateFormat`, which returns the entire pattern (in your case, `'INCDR'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_ss_SSS'*.csv'`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("'INCDR'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_ss_SSS'*.csv'");
    SimpleDateFormat sd2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_ss_SSS_'INCDR'_yyyy_MM_dd'*.csv'");

    System.out.println(sd.toPattern().replace("'INCDR'", "").replace("'*.csv'", ""));
    System.out.println(sd2.toPattern().replace("'INCDR'", "").replace("'*.csv'", ""));
```

Output:

```
yyyy_MM_dd_HH_ss_SSS
HH_ss_SSS__yyyy_MM_dd
```

Comment: This won't help me because the pattern is dynamic, Inside the code I don't know what pattern the user has defined